# How to move a glTF model in the direction it is facing in A-frame?

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I have a gltf model of my robot loaded in A-frame scene version 1.0.4. So far I can turn the robot about its x,y, z axes, but when I try to move it forward it still moves in its initial direction rather than the direction it's facing. I want to be able to control its movements with my keyboard without using any external libraries. I believe I have to use Quaternions, but I haven't figured out how to use them yet. Here is my A-frame code so far.

```html
<a-scene id="myScene">
  <a-entity environment="preset:forest;"></a-entity>

 <a-entity gltf-model="#humanoid" id="robot" position="0 20 0" rotation="0 0          0" 
   scale="0.0001 0.0001 0.0001" static-body>
 </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

And here is my script

```js
const robot = document.getElementById('robot');

const update = () => {
   if (keys.forward) {
       let {x,y,z} = robot.object3D.position;
       let ry = robot.object3D.rotation.y;
       z += Math.cos(ry * Math.PI/180)/12;
       x += Math.sin(ry * Math.PI/180)/12;
       robot.object3D.position.set(x, y, z); 
}
   else if (keys.backwards) {
       let {x, y, z} = robot.object3D.position;
       let ry = robot.object3D.rotation.y;
       z -= Math.cos(ry * Math.PI/180)/10;
       x -= Math.sin(ry * Math.PI/180)/10;
       robot.object3D.position.set(x, y, z);   
}
 if (keys.turnLeft) {
       let {x, y, z} = robot.getAttribute('rotation');
       y += 0.25;
       robot.setAttribute('rotation',{x,y,z});
}
    else if (keys.turnRight) {
        let {x, y, z} = robot.getAttribute('rotation');
        y -= 0.25;
        robot.setAttribute('rotation',{x,y,z});
}
}
```

Comment: Sounds like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48726018/a-frame-move-forward-in-camera-direction/48726147#48726147) thread is quite similar

Comment: This works as expected for the camera, I can move the robot in the direction the camera is facing, but cannot move it in the direction it is facing.  It shows at error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getWorldDirection')".

Comment: @jacob1 made an anwser with both your method, and getWorldDirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> let ry = robot.object3D.rotation.y;
> z += Math.cos(ry * Math.PI/180)/12;
> ```

Although `a-frame` uses degrees for rotation, `threejs` uses radians, so there is no need to convert them again:

```js
const robot = document.querySelector("a-box")
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", (evt) => {
   if (evt.key === 's') {
       let {x,y,z} = robot.object3D.position;
       let ry = robot.object3D.rotation.y;
       z += Math.cos(ry)/12;
       x += Math.sin(ry)/12;
       robot.object3D.position.set(x, y, z); 
    } else if (evt.key === 'w') {
       let {x, y, z} = robot.object3D.position;
       let ry = robot.object3D.rotation.y;
       console.log(ry)
       z -= Math.cos(ry)/10;
       x -= Math.sin(ry)/10;
       robot.object3D.position.set(x, y, z);   
     }
     if (evt.key === 'a') {
       let {x, y, z} = robot.getAttribute('rotation');
       y += 1;
       robot.setAttribute('rotation',{x,y,z});
     } else if (evt.key === 'd') {
       let {x, y, z} = robot.getAttribute('rotation');
       y -= 1;
       robot.setAttribute('rotation',{x: x,y: y,z: z});
     }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 0 0" color="#4CC3D9">
    <a-sphere radius="0.5" position="0 0 -1"></a-sphere>
  </a-box>
  <a-entity camera position="0 1.6 0"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

---

Same with `getWorldDirection`:

```js
const robot = document.querySelector("a-box")
const direction = new THREE.Vector3();
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", (evt) => {
   if (evt.key === 's') {
     // get robot direction
     robot.object3D.getWorldDirection(direction);
     // add a "speed" value
     direction.multiplyScalar(0.1)
     // add the new vector to the actual position
     robot.object3D.position.add(direction)
    } else if (evt.key === 'w') {
     robot.object3D.getWorldDirection(direction);
     direction.multiplyScalar(-0.1)
     robot.object3D.position.add(direction) 
    }
    if (evt.key === 'a') {
     let {x, y, z} = robot.getAttribute('rotation');
     y=y+1
     robot.setAttribute('rotation',{x,y,z});
    } else if (evt.key === 'd') {
     let {x, y, z} = robot.getAttribute('rotation');
     y=y-1
     robot.setAttribute('rotation',{x: x,y: y,z: z});
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 0 0" color="#4CC3D9">
    <a-sphere radius="0.5" position="0 0 -1"></a-sphere>
  </a-box>
  <a-entity camera position="0 1.6 0"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: agree with all that Diarmid said(+1), just wanted to let you know why your script doesnt work

Comment: Thanks, the getWorldDirection method works as I wanted in all possible angles of rotation. But the controls lag a little. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using quatenions is a good way to solve this.

You can simply apply the robot's current quaternion to a vector3 representing the movement you want to make in the robt's original rotation, and apply that to the robot's position.

Something like this:

```
fowardVector = new Vector3(0, 0, -0.1)
rotatedForwardVector = new Vector3();

rotatedForwardVector.copy(forwardVector);
rotatedForwardVector.applyQuaternion(robot.object3D.quaternion);
robot.object3D.position.add(rotatedForwardVector);
```

Note that you'll want to only create the Vector3s once, and then re-use them to avoid unecessary garbage collection, rather than creating them for each movement.

E.g using a closure as explained [here](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/best-practices.html#tick-handlers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Quaternions and many other ways, but Object3D has some usesful and more simple alternatives to move object in local coordinates:

I think the most simple one is to use https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.translateZ

```
robot.object3D.translateZ(amountToMoveForward);
```

Also https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.localToWorld can be used to transform vectors.